# How to deploy codenode

Tags: python, django

Aloha everyone,

So I was hoping to deploy codenode 'http://codenode.org/', on my website nested within a page. For the life of me I just can't follow the documentation and figure out what I'm supposed to do.

It only ever seems to talk about running things locally from the terminal, how are you supposed to set it up with regards to views, models and templates?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're simply telling you to install it via pip and virtualenv. This isn't terribly difficult to do on a host that is very Django and Python friendly, such as [WebFaction](http://webfaction.com/). You can always put the necessary files where they need to go so that they will be added to your Python path via FTP, etc.

Comment: I had managed to install it, as you said that was simple. I just don't understand where to go from there, I don't understand how to actually integrate it into my website as the installation made no noticeable changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's something I can't help with, but they do have a mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/codenode-devel